# Two calendars are shown due to addition of two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm using datepicker in my code. I originally used datepicker from [this script](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js).

Now I'm using [this script](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js) for doing pagination on my page. So after adding the second script inside my code, the page is showing me two calendars wherein I just want to use the one getting loaded from 1st script. How to remove the second calendar appearing on page?

[image: This is how it looks. I just want the 2nd calendar, the one being displayed below.]

Also one more thing, I'm adding the pagination script like this:

```
    var todoApp = angular.module('todoController', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

using the ui.bootstrap and then add the datepicker directive to it. This is the main reason for it showing me two calendars. But I'm unable to get rid of it.

Comment: Are you still including http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js?

Comment: Yes, I want the datepicker from jquery link. And not the bootstrap one.

Answer (score 0):

With the bootstrap datepicker the input type should be set to text. If you set the input type to date it is going to display the native datepicker as well. Change the input type to text and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The two calendars appearing on my page were due to the directive I included in my controller file. I used `datepicker` as directive which the ui-bootstrap as well as  my own directive both were using.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center datepicker" ng-model="formData.endDate" placeholder="Choose end date" datepicker/>

todoApp.directive("datepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var updateModel = function (dateText) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
            });
        };
        var options = {
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                updateModel(dateText);
            },
            minDate: -0
                // maxDate: "+1M +10D"
        };
        elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

Previously the directive name was `datepicker` which was conflicting with the `datepicker` directive already existing in `ui-bootstrap` code. So I changed my directive name in code to :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center datepicker" ng-model="formData.endDate" placeholder="Choose end date" mydatepicker/>

todoApp.directive("mydatepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var updateModel = function (dateText) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
            });
        };
        var options = {
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                updateModel(dateText);
            },
            minDate: -0
                // maxDate: "+1M +10D"
        };
        elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

Instead of using `datepicker` as the name for directive, I used `mydatepicker`. And hence the conflict was resolved.